# Media Foundation: Как выбрать Media stream из нескольких в Media source?

Tags: c++, windows, com, windows-media-foundation

Каков алгоритм выбора потока из источника (Media stream из Media source). Затестил на своей встроенной в ноут вебке, она дает 2 потока, причем во втором во всех медиа-типах frame rate=1. Но ведь во всех приложениях, в которых я как то использую эту вебку, нет никакого выбора потока, есть только выбор media type'а. Так каков алгоритм выбора потока? Либо же надо просто брать первый? Для каких целей тогда существует второй?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разобрался сам. Оказалось, что второй поток - не видео, а still-image. Хотя MajorType у обоих MFMediaType_Video. Видимо, это недочет Media Foundation.

Подробнее: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32658052/media-foundation-is-incorrectly-marking-still-image-capture-stream-descriptors-a